# eledmac parallel pages: \numberlinefalse to disable line numbers stops working after one page

Tags: eledmac, eledpar

I'm typesetting on parallel pages using `eledmac` and `eledpar`. I want line numbers only on the left page. So I'm using `\pstart[\nuberlinefalse]` for every `\pstart` on the right side. However, the line numbers reappear if one `\pstart...\pend` stretches on more than one page.

See this MEW:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lipsum,eledmac,eledpar}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{pages}
    \begin{Leftside}\beginnumbering

    \pstart
        \lipsum[1]
    \pend

    \endnumbering\end{Leftside}

    \begin{Rightside}\beginnumbering

    \pstart[\numberlinefalse]
        \lipsum[1-7]
    \pend

    \endnumbering\end{Rightside}
\end{pages} 
\Pages
\end{document}
```

The right side has so much text that it breaks to a second right page. Line numbers do not appear on the first page, but reappear on the second.

Is this a bug or did I operate the `\numberlinefalse` wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

`\numberlinefalse` is a global setting, and should be called only as global setting. It was created for people who wanted to have parallel typesetting but not line number.

When you call it in the optional argument of `\pstart`, it is called when eledpar starts typetsetting the pstart. In internal code of eledpar, we are in a group, for the page, and that why it is reset at page end.

When I added `\numberlinefalse` I didn't think some people would like to have line only in one side. So that is why there is `\numberlineRfalse` which should be more consistent. However, it's too late to break compatibility.

So if you don't want to have line number in right side, the best way is to say the first right line number is, for example, 1000000000. To do it, calle `\firstlinenumber` inside the `rightside` environment.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lipsum,eledmac,eledpar}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{pages}
    \begin{Leftside}\beginnumbering

    \pstart
        \lipsum[1]
    \pend

    \endnumbering\end{Leftside}

    \begin{Rightside}
    \firstlinenum{1000000000}
    \beginnumbering

    \pstart[]
        \lipsum[1-7]
    \pend

    \endnumbering\end{Rightside}
\end{pages} 
\Pages
\end{document}
```

Comment: don't forget to validate if it ok.

Comment: Yes it works so far!